# Edit search vertical at site level

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

I can no longer update search verticals a site level on SharePoint Online, the **Edit** button is no longer visible.
[image]

I guess it is not a permission issue because it was working fine yesterday and nothing changed regarding permissions.

I can reproduce the issue on multiple tenants.

P.S.: I followed the steps described here: https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-configure-search-verticals-on-a-sharepoint-site/

Am I missing something ?

Comment: What permission do you have on this site, Site Owner/Site collection administrator? Can you check on another site where you have site owner permissions and see if you are able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I just checked on our SharePoint site and I am unable to see the Edit button as well.

Comment: Yes, I am site owner (and site admin)

Comment: Try raising support ticket with Microsoft directly and report this behavior: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support